# Proposal to drop "& Usage" from the site title

Tags: discussion

**Update 11/25: Thanks for your feedback! We're going to go ahead and drop "& Usage" from the site title.** The header image and the "official" language around the site (in the help center and about page, for example) should be updated within the next few days.

---

I'm Laura, a product manager at Stack Exchange.

I wanted to let this community know that I've started a discussion over on Meta Stack Overflow about some general guidelines for naming our sites, specifically our language sites, going forward. Feel free to [read and discuss my post over there](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207404/standardizing-simplifying-se-site-names).

The gist of my proposal is that "& Usage" generally makes a site name longer and more difficult to say and type without adding much, if any, meaning.

**We'd like to rename existing Stack Exchange language sites to just "X Language" and drop "& Usage" from both existing sites and any new language sites we launch in the future.**

This means the header image on the site would simply read "Russian Language" rather than "Russian Language & Usage", and all of the official documentation would drop "& Usage" as well. The site URL would not change.

We've already done this with our Italian Language site (in private beta at the time of this writing), and [they were pleased](https://italian.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60/why-is-this-language-stack-exchange-site-named-italian-language-while-all-oth) with the simpler name. Until now, our language sites have followed the naming convention of "X Language & Usage Stack Exchange", but why? It seemed to make sense at the time, but as we've grown, it's become clear that "& Usage" isn't really necessary. A site about a particular language is, by definition, concerned with the usage of that language — that's where all the questions come from!

Before we actually make any changes to existing sites, I wanted to hear any concerns you might have. I feel like a shorter, simpler name is a big win for everyone, but please feel free to post concerns about this particular community here, or any general concerns over on [the main MSO thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207404/standardizing-simplifying-se-site-names).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just "Russian language" is fine with me.

Answer (score 3):

I actually never understood what this "& Usage" is supposed to mean. I attributed it to my poor English. Is it contraction from "Russian language and its usage"? This make some sence, but as it stands it reads "Russian language and Russian Usage". What is "Russian Usage"? Is it grammatical at all?

I thought it is more clear for those whose native language is English, because for me it sounds like "Russian customs" or "Russian way of life", or "The way Russians use things".

Comment: I believe it's supposed to be more like your first point - a contraction of "Russian language and *its* usage". Even if that's the case, it's redundant (you can't really learn about the Russian language without learning about its usage), so we're going to get rid of it. Just wanted to make sure no one had any objections first!